# Build new array out of two keeping values in order

Tags: php, html

I have two arrays:

```
a:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 5
)

b:
Array
(
    [0] => Sentry
    [1] => Maxima
)
```

and I'm trying to get a new array that looks like this

```
c:
Array
(
    ["Sentry"] => 2
    ["Maxima"] => 5
)
```

It just so happens that the 0th and 1st element in each array line up nicely if I could just get them together into the same array I think I could continue. I tried doing this manually (although I prefer to use a for loop):

```
$c[] = $b[0] => $a[0]
```

But obviously that is wrong.

results in:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\mine\complex_csv\to_array.php on line 7

Comment: Can I please get this reopened? I understand why you closed it but I have totally rephrased my question. I see now that array_combine() handled this fine. I will delete post when it will allow it.

Comment: Of course. You have my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php

$a = array(2, 5);
$b = array('Sentry', 'Maxima');

print_r(array_combine($b, $a));
```

Comment: Thans, yes I stumbled across array_combine on my own if you look at the previous notes.